# How long is one a "new contributor"?

Tags: support, new-contributor-indicator

Plain curiosity: what actions will render a newbie an "ordinary" contributor, so that the "new contributor" indications will no longer show up for that account?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

From [meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator?cb=1):

> Folks will see an indicator when they go to interact with new contributors (visible for a week following their first post)

The indicator is specific for each site, and it doesn't take into account the association bonus or rep in any other form.

Please note that the **account's** age is irrelevant. What matters is how old is the first contributed post for a user in a particular site.

Additionally, for any site in the network its respective meta it's considered a separate site as well (which makes sense, since meta sites have their own rules and culture).

So if a user has been a member for several years without contributing any questions or answers, whenever they finally post either, you'll get that banner in their posts, or when commenting in their posts.

Comment: From my reading of it, it doesn't take anything useful into account. I could never have posted anything but have 2k rep from SEs, do some reviews, lots of helpful flags etc. Then get a new contributor banner on me like I don't know how the site works. </rant>

Comment: @TheLethalCoder but in order to do it, you need first get the [prvilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to do so. So you need to post something first. Still agree, it does not add much value.

Comment: I noticed `new contributor` for the first time today.   if the post is on a tag that the user has not posted on before?

Comment: found this: [new contributor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372908/what-is-constitutes-as-being-a-new-contributor?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @TheLethalCoder it also shows up if it is your [first post on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314474/add-a-way-for-users-to-opt-out-of-the-new-contributor-indicator-on-their-own-p/314479#314479) no matter your experience with main and the first time you post on a new SE site (despite contributor bonus) it will also show up

Comment: I just noticed the effect @JGreenwell mentioned and I'll just say: *That's pretty weird.*

Comment: Meta and main sites are seen as separate in this regard?

Comment: @Peter Yes. Meta and Main are separate sites for this too.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt You could gain rep from suggested edits.  You can get to 1K rep without a single post. That gives you access to review queues, flags, and chat

Comment: Whoops. Wow, I thought there was something like an Edit privilge. Thanks for correcting. @NathanOliver But still, I think it is very unliky that a user is contributing by only editing (Probably more likly on Meta).

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Most likely it wouldn't happen.  I just wanted to point out it could happen.  I've often suggest new users spend some time doing edits and watching to see how the site works and get a feel for it.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder You mean like [Peter Mortensen](https://stackexchange.com/users/24885/peter-mortensen?tab=accounts), who has several accounts with a decent amount of rep but no contributions to Q/A? He's been on the site for years, but if he made a post on any of the sites where he hasn't *yet*, he'd get a "new contributor" badge, which is utter nonsense! "New contributor" should be based on some metric with reputation taken into account. Seems like the SO "be nice" issue got extrapolated to the network in a bad way...

Comment: I think the reason each site counts separately is that while you can be familiar with the SE system, that doesn't necessarily mean you're familiar with each specific site and its rules.

Comment: Hypothetically if somebody posted, deleted their post, then undeleted it (is that possible?) a week later would that prevent the badge from showing?

Comment: Does 7 day count get reset if a user deletes their question? I see a lot of people deleting their questions .....

Answer (score 6):

The "New contributor" label will display for a week after the user's first posting per site, regardless of how long they've had their account on that site.

Some people have said that this does not provide any useful information because you can already see their rep points. However, just because someone has 101 rep, that doesn't necessarily make them a new contributor. They could have posted a question or an answer more than a week ago that received no votes.

Comment: Does 7 day count get reset if a user deletes their question? I see a lot of people deleting their questions .....