# What is (constitutes as being) a new contributor?

Tags: support, new-contributor-indicator

I posted [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator?cb=1#comment1030663_314287) to Tim Post asking about what constitutes as being a new contributor.

I searched on Google for "what is a new contributor Stack Overflow meta" and "what is a new contributor" in the search input on Meta Stack Exchange, but I came up empty.

Here is what I don't understand. I noticed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51966378/1415724) from [this member](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9996383/dieter-kr%c3%a4utl) this morning and there is the "New contributor" message showing up under their member name in the answer. Shouldn't that be showing for "new" members only who have not contributed in any way, be it a question or answer?

The description under: ***"The new indicator works by the age of a user's first visible post."*** in the Meta Stack Exchange post [Come Take a Look at our New Contributor Indicator!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314287/231583) being *"This could be a question **or** answer,"* to me doesn't seem to fit the bill here. If it's an "or", then why is that "New contributor" message showing in their answer under their member name?

My questions are:

- What "does" constitute as being a "New contributor"?
- Is this a bug or is it because they have not asked any questions yet and have only contributed with answers?

[They](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9996383/dieter-kr%c3%a4utl) have been a member (on Stack Overflow) for 58 days now (as of today).

I took a screenshot of what I saw just in case it disappears.

[image]

**Edit:**

About the possible duplicate: I feel it does not answer my question since I have seen the "New contributor" message show up only for new members lately who have posted new questions or answers, not for ones that have been here for a while.

Comment: @yivi I have edited; I feel it does not answer what I am asking. But thanks though.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand why you think the case you are posting about contradicts the _"it depends on on the age of their first visible post"._

Comment: @yivi I have a problem with Tim's *"This could be a question **or** answer"* under  *"The new indicator works by the age of a user's first visible post"*.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Oh so you mean someone that only asks questions for 1 year and then answers one should be considered a new contributor?

Comment: Still don't understand. First visible post. Could be a question or an answer. What's unclear about it? In the case you linked, their oldest contribution is about a day old, for example.

Comment: @yivi [See my comment here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372908/what-is-constitutes-as-being-a-new-contributor#comment623413_372909), that's what's happening for me; the time they've been a member for, as opposed to the recent post/answer.

Comment: But it says explicitely in the text you quote it depends on the age of their first contribution, not the age of the account... right?

Comment: @yivi It was the age of the account that confused me.

Comment: @Rakete1111 That would just confuse me more *lol!* See my above comment to yivi.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Users are considered "new contributors" for one week (7 days) after their first post, regardless of when the account was registered.  This specific user has no questions and their oldest answer is from only 2 days ago.  This means they meet the criteria for being a "new contributor" even though they have [22 answers within these 2 days](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9996383/dieter-kr%C3%A4utl?tab=answers).

It's all about the recency of the first post (whether it's a question or answer), not the volume of activity.  And it will continue to appear on all things related to this user for the entire week.

Comment: Can you read my question again, most particularly about the ***"or"*** on *"The new indicator works by the age of a user's first visible post"*.

Comment: Their first post (an answer) was 2 days ago, so the system considers them new.  Where is the confusion?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I think this is the right answer. Age of the account does not matter (so any discussion about 58 days is out). What matters is the age of the first post, be it *either* a question *or* an answer

Comment: @Federico Hm... yeah...  it's confusing for me. However, the member has been there for 58 days, that's probably why it's confusing.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Thanks for clarifying that for me. I'll mark it as correct in a few mins.

Comment: @ryanyuyu In response to your: *"Where is the confusion?"* - [See my comment here...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372908/what-is-constitutes-as-being-a-new-contributor?noredirect=1#comment623419_372908) that was why it was confusing to me. [yivi posted this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372908/what-is-constitutes-as-being-a-new-contributor?noredirect=1#comment623418_372908) which helped me to realize that, being the latter part of their comment.

Comment: I am glad this feature was added when I first started answering on StackExchange, how some responded to my answers felt over critical. Despite this being a dink or swim approach, which actually aided me, I still found beginning quite formidable. To the extent, I thought "why bother if my insight does not feel appreciated!". However I came to realise the high quality of answers was maintained by this approach, but I believe the "new contributor" will help ease those into the site more and mitigate this deterring atmosphere I described.