# Do answers have to be "standalone"? Can an answer add useful information to another answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette

So recently a comment I put in an answer turned out to be useful (from another comment responded to me) so I turned it into an answer like this:

> To add to the current answer, you need to ...

The answer itself is good but it's easy to overlook a fact that would cause problem that would cost a lot of time to find out. I believe this answer would help future visitors who may come to the question.

Later a comment states:

> answers should stand alone without having to read other answers first. please adjust accordingly.

Is this actually a policy? I believe I see a lot of answers (ironically I can't even give an example now) which basically is, "abc's answer is good but to add ..." which is very helpful and have a lot of upvotes too.

---

Update: for my specific post, I added a few more context:

> ...'s answer (with link) is correct but I want to add additional context in case you have problem with ...

and add a shortened code snippet (basically just the accepted answer but emphasize the part that is important).

Comment: I would suggest that the problem is more that you state *"To add to the current answer"*, but there can be *many* current answers (yours is also a current answer). You should really reference the answer and add context to the part you specifically mean. Adding a code snippet to show how the new solution looks would likely be useful too. (This is all stated as a non-SME in Swift.)

Comment: *"believed I have posted here before years ago."* You have no undeleted posts on your account here on Meta and you don't have any badges that could indicate you've posted here before. Unfortunately the [meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372908/2029983) (and it's duplicate target) on the subject doesn't denote if a user can become a new contributor again if their post is deleted and they post a new one.

Comment: In 2014 MSO was split up and the old posts were moved to [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162797/luke-vo).

Comment: @ThomA thanks, there's only one answer and it's accepted. I edited my answer to add exact reference to it. As per the meta, I realized it was Meta Stack Exchange, I didn't know we have separate Meta SE vs. Meta SO now.

Comment: *"there's only one answer and it's accepted"* Right now, but that could change. Don't assume a question will only ever have 1 (other) answer.

Comment: relevant image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAUaw.png

Comment: The important piece missing is whether the answer would *still* fully answer the question if the third party answer were deleted or (drastically) edited. Is that what you have in mind, or does your hypothetical answer become nonsense without the other one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Do answers have to be "standalone"?

Yes.

Paraphrasing [ChrisF](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398364) here:

> An answer is what they believe is the solution to your problem. It's seen as a permanent artefact of the site. [...] Answers should be complete and self contained and only use links [...] as references and backup for what's being asserted in the answer. The answer should be useful despite the links, not because of them.

And for the the other part of your question:

> Can an answer add useful information to another answer?

Yes.

Newer answers can build on existing answers to offer new or different insights, caveats etc. in how to problem in the question can be solved. Do know that all answers can be community edited. If there only is some complementary/trivial information to be shared, editing the existing answer might be a better option. Provide a clarifying edit comment (don't break the CoC!) and maybe leave an extra comment under the answer to make anyone aware why you added stuff to the answer. The comment can later be deleted when the OP confirms they have seen your edit or after 6 to 8 weeks, whichever comes first.

Comment: This is much better. I will proceed as you suggest.

Comment: _"Provide a clarifying edit comment (don't break the CoC!) "_ - lol